# Q# Grover Tutorial Problem

Tags: programming, grovers-algorithm, q#

Referring to the Q# tutorial on Grover algorithm in https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/quantum/tutorial-qdk-grovers-search?tabs=tabid-visualstudio, I replicated the code exactly in Visual Studio Code and used a Python host program to run it.

I tried to run it with N_Experiments(=100 for example) times but it always hanged or stopped after a few times. For instance, it will hang at Experiment 37 out of 100 or 45 out of 100, etc. I don't know what is wrong with it. Is the problem caused by my system itself or is it due to the underlying code? I wonder if anyone out there has faced similar problem. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: What number are you running it for?

Comment: 21, which is the same as the tutorial. It works because when I set N_Experiments to a low number, say 10, it shows a majority of the measurements as 1, 3, 7, 21. However, when I increased the N_Experiment to 100 in order to get a better average, it hanged halfway through.